# How to apply macro from file1 to file2?

Tags: excel, vba

I have .csv files with different filenames put on a shared drive twice a day.

I need to apply a macro I wrote, (with much help) to the most recently created file with no user input so I can add it to Windows Task Scheduler.

For the task scheduler part I was going to use a PowerShell script.

How do I have Excel open a macro from file1 and run it on file2, where the filename on file2 changes daily?

Comment: I would recommend looking into using an Excel Add-In (XLAM file) - But if you wrote all of your code using `Select` and `Activate` you are going to have to rewrite it regardless.

Comment: SO is not a code creation platform. Please add what have you tried and users in SO will help you with whats wrong in it or what a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to store your macro in Personal Macro Workbook. With that you can run it on every excel file you open.
Here is how you do it:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790